# Searching for a range

Tags: python, search, range

I have a list of integers in ascending order and a target value. And I would like to return the index of the first and last of the target value. Here is my code:

```
nums = [3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
target = 5

class Solution:
    def searchRange(self,nums, target):

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == target:
                left_index = i
                break

            else:
                return [-1,-1]


        for j in range(len(nums)-1,-1,-1):
            if nums[j] == target:
                right_index = j
                break

        return [left_index,right_index]

x = Solution()
print(x.searchRange(nums,5))
```

The output that I am getting is [-1,-1], i.e. the target is not in the list. However 5 is clearly in the list and the desired output should be [2,4]. ANY HELP WOULD BE GREAT!

Comment: What have done to try debug your code? Have you even tried adding print statements every time round the loop and when the value is matched?

Comment: Look at your first `if...` block. If the condition is not met, execution drops to the `else...` block where you `return [-1,-1]`.

Comment: What you need to do is to delete the else and initiate the left_index and the right_index to -1

Comment: Or did you perhaps intend for the `else` be part of `for...else...` instead of part of `if...else...`? Indentation is key.

Comment: You might find it easier to use `find()` and `rfind()`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @barny Lists don't have those methods. I think you're thinking of strings. I thought so too.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == target:
        left_index = i
        break
    else:
        return [-1,-1]
```

When it's executing the for-loop for the first time, `nums[i]` has a value of 3.
3 is not equal to 5 (your target), so it will execute the else statement and directly return `[-1, -1]`.

If you now unindent the `else` statement by one level, it will only be executed AFTER the for-loop has iterated over all numbers [[reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)]. If your target value is found, the `break` keyword will prevent the else statement from getting executed.

So, the following would work:

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == target:
        left_index = i
        break
else:
    return [-1,-1]
```

Do NOT remove the else part, or you would get a `NameError` for `left_index` <strike>and `right_index`</strike> if your target is not found in the numbers!

Add an `else` statement to the second for loop, too (to avoid a `NameError` for `right_index` when target is not found a second time in nums):

```py
nums = [3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
target = 5

class Solution:
    def searchRange(self, nums, target):
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == target:
                left_index = i
                break
        else:
            return [-1, -1]

        for j in range(len(nums)-1, -1, -1):
            if nums[j] == target:
                right_index = j
                break
        else:
            return [left_index, -1]

        return [left_index, right_index]

x = Solution()
print(x.searchRange(nums, target))
```

Comment: You don't actually need an `else` on the second loop. If there's no second occurrence, `right_index` will be the same as `left_index`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going through the first loop `for i in range(len(nums))`, clearly the first element in your list is not your target. So your `else` statement is getting executed and thus it returns `[-1, -1]`. Remove the `else` part. You can set your `left_index` and `right_index` as `-1` initially, so if the search is not successful this value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You got [-1, -1] because in the first loop, if the first element is not equal to the desired one, then else is executed.

This should help you!

```
nums = [3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9]
target = 5

class Solution:
    def searchRange(self,nums, target):

        n = len(nums)
        left_index = -1
        for i in range(n):
            if nums[i] == target:
                left_index = i
                break
        if left_index == -1:
            return [-1, -1]

        for j in range(n-1, -1 , -1):
            if nums[j] == target:
                right_index = j 
                break

        return [left_index, right_index]

x = Solution()
print(x.searchRange(nums,5))
```